# How to get a city inside a specific country with Faker

Tags: php, laravel-5, faker

I'm working with the Faker extension in Laravel 5 to populate my database.

I have  "countries" and "Cities" tables so I called

```
$faker->country
```

but how can I get a city that is inside that country?

I don't want "Bogotá" to belong to "EEUU".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'd make a generator and add only the provider for that country ([a list of them can be found here](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#language-specific-formatters)):

```
$faker = new Faker\Generator();
$faker->addProvider(new Faker\Provider\en_AU\Address($faker));
$faker->state; // will give you only Australian states
```

If your specific need isn't covered by the available providers, you may need to create a custom provider.

Comment: @Ahmed It's very possible Faker's syntax has changed slightly in five years, but "not working" is hardly very useful feedback I can address.

Comment: how would you do this dynamically? ie. first randomly select a country (Australia) then get  a state from it?

Answer (score -2):

In Laravel factory,This should do the trick.

```
use Faker\Provider\en_AU\Address;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'country' => $this->faker->country(),
            'city' => $this->faker->city(),
            'state' => Address::state(),
        ];
    }
```